# Appending a numpy array to a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some trouble populating a pandas `DataFrame`. I am following the instructions found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) to produce a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame`. The example work fine except that I want to have an array instead of a single value.

```
activity = 'Open_Truck'
id = 1
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(activity, id)], names=['activity', 'id'])
v = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1, 5), index=index)
```

> Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

If I replace `randn(1, 5)` with `randn(1)` it works fine. For `randn(1, 1)` I should use `randn(1, 1).flatten('F')` but also works.
When trying:

```
v = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1, 5).flatten('F'), index=index)
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

My intention is to add 1 feature vector (they are `np.array` of course in real case scenario and not `np.random.randn`) for each `activity` and `id` in each row.
So, How do I manage to add an array in a `MultiIndex` `DataFrame`?

Edit:
As I am new to pandas I mixed `Series` with `DataFrame`. I can achieve the above using `DataFrame` which is two-dimensional by default:

```
arrays = [np.array(['Open_Truck']*2),
            np.array(['1', '2'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4), index=arrays)
df
               0         1         2         3
Open 1 -0.210923  0.184874 -0.060210  0.301924
     2  0.773249  0.175522 -0.408625 -0.331581
```

Comment: I see your edit, there is same principe, need index with same length as MultiIndex.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem `MultiIndex` has only one tuple and data length is different, `5` so lengths not match:

```
activity = 'Open_Truck'
id = 1
#get 5 times tuples
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(activity, id)] * 5, names=['activity', 'id'])
print (index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Open_Truck'], [1]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['activity', 'id'])

print (len(index))
5

v = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1, 5).flatten('F'), index=index)
print (v)
activity    id
Open_Truck  1    -1.348832
            1    -0.706780
            1     0.242352
            1     0.224271
            1     1.112608
dtype: float64
```

In first aproach lengths are same, `1`, because one tuple in list:

```
activity = 'Open_Truck'
id = 1
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(activity, id)], names=['activity', 'id'])

print (len(index))
1

v = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1), index=index)
print (v)
activity    id
Open_Truck  1    -1.275131
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, but in this way I get an array column-wise. Is there any way to get it row-wise? When I append new arrays they are added below the previous one.